# Partial form validation in Angular 2

Tags: forms, angular

In following example, is there a way to validate only one `form-step`s inputs?

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <form-step>
     <input name="name" required />
     <input name="email" required />
  </form-step>
  <form-step>
     <input name="phone" required />
     <input name="somethingElse" required />
  </form-step>
</form>
```

And `FormStepComponent` like so (simplified):

```
template: `
<form #stepForm="ngForm">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</form>
`

@ViewChild('stepForm') _form;
public get invalid(): boolean {
  return this._form.invalid;
}
```

I want to implement function `invalid` on the form-step component, that would check, if any of its containing inputs is invalid according to their directives just like the `f.invalid` does for the whole form.

The provided example doesn't work, because the inputs are bound to the topmost form.

Answer (score 0):

So after some trying I ended up setting [`ngModelGroup`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModelGroup-directive.html) on each `form-step`

```
<form #f="ngForm">
  <form-step ngModelGroup="mg1">
     <input name="name" required />
     <input name="email" required />
  </form-step>
  <form-step ngModelGroup="mg2">
     <input name="phone" required />
     <input name="somethingElse" required />
  </form-step>
</form>
```

And accessing it using [`ContentChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ContentChild-decorator.html)

```
import { ContentChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModelGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'form-step',
    template: `
    <div>
      <!-- ... -->
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </div>
  `
})
export class FormStepComponent {    

  //...

  @ContentChild(NgModelGroup) _modelGroup;
  public get invalid(): boolean {
    return this._modelGroup.invalid;
  }
}
```

This is just a "best guess" approach. I would like to avoid having the `ngModelGroup` directive on all `form-step`s, but I don't know how to create it implicitly.